# Redirect user to login page after password reset with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have devise setup in my Rails 4 application with single table inheritance. I am trying to have the Business user redirected to the login page once they've reset their password. 
I am using the devise after_resetting_password_path_for method. As of right now after the user updates their password the user is logged out and redirected to the index page.

*routes.rb*

```
devise_for :businesses, skip: :sessions, :controllers => {:registrations => "businesses/registrations", :passwords => "businesses/passwords"}
```

**passwords_controller.rb**

```
class Businesses::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  protected
    def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
      new_user_session_path
    end
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :class => "sky-form", :id => "sky-form4" }) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Your new password"  %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Your new password again"  %>
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, :placeholder => "Your current password"  %>
    <%= f.submit "Save Changes", :class => "btn btn-u" %>
<% end %>
```

**console output**

```
 SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "encrypted_password" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Business') AND "users"."id" = 7  [["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$5M/ooIQCqUORX7mMS1Xxn.5iRFnwnYvr4Hz.LIpOCKPpi3jPogAlK"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-17 00:32:12.162620"]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
```

Comment: if you put a breakpoint just before new_user_session_path does the server stop at this location? Just to make sure that after_resetting_password_path_for is actually called.

Comment: @Typpex good thought. I just inserted 'break line' above the new_user_session_path and the server didn't stop.

Comment: I meant a breakppoint. If you write debugger and you launch your server with -u option such as rails server -u then your server should stop when it reaches the debugger line

Comment: @Typpex I'm using a pry breakpoint that I've used in other controllers and this one isn't working. So it seems as if the update isn't passing the the user to the after_password_reset method. Any ideas why?

Comment: The console output seems correct but how come the edit.html.erb form url is registration_path(resource_name), i think it should be password_path(resource_name) or maybe something along businesses_password_path(resource_name) in your case.